# setting the right permissions for public web folder

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php

I have configured my VPS server (ubuntu 18.04) to run multiple domains and one of the webserver will be an opencart store (actually I have to move an opencart store from a shared hosting to a vps server)

I am not sure what permissions to give the store to work properly. In the old hosting in Cpanel the permissions was 755 for folders and 644 for files.

I moved the store from Cpanel to the VPS (using ssh) to:

```
/var/www/opecart/public
```

All the content is in the public folder.

The persmissions that I give it:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data /var/www/opencart/public
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/opencart/public
```

and it`s not loadind the page.....it complains:

```
Warning: fopen(/var/www/opencart/public/system/logs/error.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/opencart/public/system/library/log.php
```

If I set to 775 it work fine.

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/opencart/public
```

It is ok to leave this permissions 775 for opencart ????

Comment: No. You have a configuration issue. See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/a/49477207/2920227 from out sister site but the opencart forum is loaded with these kind of errors :) Permissions: folders should be 755, cache folder 777, scripts that run 755, images and template files 644. `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/opencart/public` is BAD. You need TWO of these: 1 for files. 1 for directories: `find /var/www/opencart/public -type f -print0|xargs -0 chmod 644` and `find /var/www/opencart/public -type d -print0 |xargs -0 chmod 755`

Comment: @Rinzwind Why use 777 on cache? Would not be enough 775 ? I gave the folders 755, files 644, cache and logs folder 775 and it seems to work. Plese correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Oh 775 works too if "others" are not allowed in. Thing is: if there is a problem using cache your server or application will crash.